# Detect iOS Google+ Sign In was incomplete.

Tags: ios, google-plus

By "incomplete" I'm referring to a particular user journey

- user opens iOS application, and chooses Google+ to sign in.
- Google SDK navigates user to G+ application for sign in (or webview if G+ not installed).
- user navigates away from Google+ (tapping home button for instance) ***without*** accepting or denying permissions requested.
- user navigates back to iOS application.

Using Facebook SDK, when application becomes active, the sign in session is closed if the user follows similar journey via the call to

`[FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActive];`

It appears that there is nothing as advanced from Google+ SDK.

How can I detect that the user never completed the Google+ sign in journey?

Using iOS7, Google+ SDK

`pod 'google-plus-ios-sdk', '~> 1.5'`

Comment: Be aware that Apple will reject your app if you use Google Sign In that directs the user into Safari(i.e. The default behavior of their SDK) https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=900

Comment: I guess you can easily have a `NSUserDefault` and save the journey, from triggering in Login to finishing it up, if not it has not completed, I have never used Google Plus. Just a thought. See if it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the situation described, that a user has skipped the authentication process of Google Sign in or has navigate to Home Screen by tapping home button.

**1st Way:-**

On that basis,  GPPSignInDelegate never gets called

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error: (NSError *) error {
    NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);
}
```

Now, if the developer is saving the Google Plus auth key in NSUserDefault or a in a plist or in local DB , then he directly check it in didBecomeActive method of AppDelegate .

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  //Check whether Google Plus auth key is present from the stored location or variable    
}
```

**2nd Way:-**

In applicationDidBecomeActive method one can directly check if authentication is completed or not

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
    {
       if ([[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authentication]) {
             // The user has  signed in properly
           }
        else
         {
               // The user has  not  signed in properly
         }
    }
```

Comment: l had the same problem like yours and solved it by this method only,

Comment: Yes, but you should also keep an iVar to be sure the user is attempting a Login with Google+ before thinking the user did abort the Google+ signin. So you should keep on the delegate an Boolean iVar, like `isLoggingInWithGoogle` which should be turned to true when the user is about to log in with Google+, and then check if it's true in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` before validating the login

Comment: How come it does't work in iOS 7? It is tested and verified.Check from your end once.